# Unwanted scroll on click (only on Iphone)

Tags: jquery, css, iphone

This problem appears only on Iphones. At the website https://kumat.sk, when you click in header "hamburger" on "Realizácie" , it scrolls you down to something like this:

[image]

But when you click on the photo, text or one of the arrows , the whole selection jumps up, like at the picture:

[image]

Can someone help me with this, bcs there is no script for anything like this in code and this is happening only on Iphones, on Android it´s working just fine...

If I should post you here some parts of code, I will do, just tell me which part...

PS: at this particular part of web I used https://flickity.metafizzy.co/, but I didn´t find connection between this and the problem.

Thanks for all your help

Comment: I believe its your lightbox plugin that does the trick, when you go to your page on a mobile and click on the image and then look at the browser you can see it set `#pid=1`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen , thanks, but it isn´t it...  I commented whole lightbox , the `#pid=1` isn´t showing anymore, but the problem is still there